# Remove final comma or final character in a txt file using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a comma delimited file like so

```
info,someinfo,moreinfo,123,
```

I want to remove the final comma in each line.

I have tried many variations of:

```
sed -i 's/.$//' filename
```

The above command seems to be the prevailing opinion of the internet, but it is not changing my file in any way.

Comment: It's not removing the last character from each line? Because that's what it should do.

Comment: Is it possible that you have trailing spaces after the last `,`.

Comment: If there are spaces and you don't want to remove them, but the last *printable* character, you should make that clear. And also if the spaces should be removed or should stay. Maybe add a few more lines of input instead of just a single one?

Answer (score 0):

if every line contains `,` as last letter you can remove like this

```
str="info,someinfo,moreinfo,123,"
echo ${str::-1}
```

**Output:**

```
 info,someinfo,moreinfo,123
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The OP is dealing with a file, not a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You may have trailing spaces after the last comma.  You could use this command instead so that it handles the optional spaces well:

```
sed -i -E 's/,[[:space:]]*$//' file
```

I am not sure if your intention is to remove the last character, regardless of whether it is a comma or not.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a DOS `\r\n` line terminated file, remove the `\r` also:

```
$ cat file
info,someinfo,moreinfo,123,
$ unix2dos file
unix2dos: converting file file to DOS format...
$ sed 's/.\r$//' file
info,someinfo,moreinfo,123
```

In awk redefining record separator `RS` to conditionally accept the `\r`. It will be removed in output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"}{sub(/.$/,"")}1' file
info,someinfo,moreinfo,123
```

If you are using GNU awk, you can add the `\r` (conditionally) to the output with `ORS=RT;` before the `print`, ie:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS="\r?\n" }  # set the record separator to accept \r if needed
{
    ORS=RT            # set the used separator as the output separator
    sub(/.$/,"")      # remove last char
}1' file              # output
info,someinfo,moreinfo,123
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:
`sed 's/\(.\)$//' file_name > filename_output`

Just redirecting the output to a new file `filename_output`.

Answer (score 0):

The command removes the last character regardless of what it is. If you want to remove the last character only if it is a comma, try

```
sed -i 's/,$//' filename
```

This will leave the other lines alone, as the regex doesn't match.

(The `-i` option is not properly portable; on BSD and thus also MacOS, you will need `-i ''`.)